# Image not loading in JPanel that is within a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, preferredsize

I have a JFrame which has 4 different Panels. The Black box on right in the image below is the Image Panel. I am trying to write a Class that will allow me to load an image into any Panel within any other class in my program.

http://sdrv.ms/14TEq2T

LoadImage.java

```
package sf;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class LoadImage extends Component {

BufferedImage img;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

public LoadImage(String filename) {
   try {         
       System.out.println(filename);
       img = new ImgUtils().scaleImage(380, 360, filename);           
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("File not found");
   }

}

class ImgUtils {

    public BufferedImage scaleImage(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String filename) {
        BufferedImage bi = null;

        try {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(filename);
            bi = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
            g2d.drawImage(ii.getImage(), 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return bi;
    }
}
}
```

Code that I use to load in the Image in my other Classes.

```
private void getProductImage() {

    try {
        String path = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        String newPath = decodedPath.replace("build/classes/", "src/productImages/");

        productImagePanel.add(new LoadImage(newPath + imageCode + ".jpg"));
        revalidate();
        pack();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The 'imageCode' is the code that is retrieved from database once the Window is visible and I have checked the Path to images several times.

The LoadImage.java works on its own and load the images if a 'main runnable' method is added to it, however I can't seem to display the image in the panel I want. Please advice on how to fix my problem, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem could very well be you're trying to load the image as a component to the JPanel. Problems include:

- the preferredSize of the Component could well be [0, 0], and so it can be trying it's little heart out to display an image but just be too small to do so.
- There could be other components already added to the JPanel
- The JPanel's layout may not play nice with newly added components.
- You shouldn't mix heavy weight (Component) with light weight (most all other non-top level Window Swing components) without a definite need.

I suggest:

- Add a JLabel to your image displaying JPanel just once on JPanel creation.
- Give your productImagePanel a method that accepts an Image or an ImageIcon and then either creates the ImageIcon from the Image or uses the ImageIcon provided to set the Icon of the JLabel.
- Be sure that the JPanel uses a layout that allows the JLabel to display itself fully. The layout manager tutorials can help with this.
- Either that or all the image displaying JPanel is for is to show the image and nothing else, get rid of it and instead use a JLabel by itself, and add your Icons directly to it.

Also as an aside: you should be disposing any Graphics and Graphics2D objects that *you* create (but not any given to you by the JVM). That means that when you're done drawing with g2d in your ImageUtilities, dispose of it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am familiar with the using JLabel's Icon as showing the images. I was trying to avoid having to use JLabel to show the Images, but I will use it if I don't get anywhere with these method..

Comment: Also, the class Imgutils in LoadImage.java is resizing the image to fit the JPanel's size, I think size isn't the problem. Also, Panel is empty with no other components when the Frame is initialised and shown.

Comment: @HMH: you could load the images into a JPanel and draw it with the JPanel's paintComponent method, but again, if you did this, I would add the JPanel to the GUI from the get-go and only change the Image portion itself. In other words, the drawing component should not change, but the image it draws may be allowed to change. But again, I'll bet that your Component's size is 0,0 or 1,1. You can test this you know by putting a `System.out.println(getSize())` in the paint method. Also, you should avoid mixing heavy and light weight components if there is no need to do this.

Comment: JPanel is already added to the GUI before the Window shows up like you said (Panel Size: 400, 400 & Images will come in size: 380, 360, that's what the ImgUtils class is for in LoadImage.java). The "Change image portion" is the thing I need help with. I will try 'paintComponent' method as you suggested, thank you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Tried your suggestion about the paintComponent but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for help.

Comment: @HMH: It's hard to say why it's not working for you since it works fine for me and for all the other Swing experts on this site. All I can guess at is that you're doing something wrong, but what, it's impossible to say.